# "You wouldn’t want to know" vs "you don’t want to know"

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

What is the difference between "You wouldn't want to" and "You don't want to"?

Also similar uses with

- You wouldn't want to do
- You wouldn't want to see

Comment: No significant difference.  "You don't want to know" is probably the more common form of idiom in the US.  Often used as a reply to a query -- "Who was that on the phone?"  "You don't want to know."

Answer (score 3):

'You wouldn't want to know', obviously given in reply to another person's question, is arguably more accurately formed, as a contraction of

> 'You wouldn't want to know if you knew how awful the truth really is'

or

> 'You wouldn't want to know if you knew how dangerous that knowledge
>   would be'.

But the paradoxical

> 'You don't want to know',

with precisely the same meaning is equally acceptable. It is a punchier variant, probably preferred in the US for that reason. 'You don't want to know' is being used to represent 'Even though you have a desire to know as evidenced by your asking the question, if I give you the facts, you'll wish you never asked.' Stick with 'You don't want to know.'